# How to change android boot logo (u-boot-logo.data)?

Tags: android, u-boot

I am trying to change the android mascot boot splash image that shows up after booting an android device. The original file for this image is named u-boot-logo.data, and is located among the firmware installation files in the folder FirmwareInstall. How may I edit and change it to a different image? What is its file format?

Comment: It is Universal Uberoid WM8650 1.5.5 HoneyCombMOD v10.1 for WM8650